# While scrolling the web page interesting effect encountered with an image....is this optic inertia?

Tags: vision

While scrolling this web page, interesting effect encountered with the image below. Is this optic inertia? The faster the scrolling, the more wavelike figures appear on three areas in the picture.

[image: 1]

Comment: …. more like some latency somewhere in the electronics than anything else.